# Dynamic Title Module Control

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, custom-module, script

I'm using PHP to creata dynamic page title based on the menu item using Sourcer and the following PHP:

```
<?php
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
echo $active->title;
?>
```

It works, but I would like to restrict the menu to the third level menu. So, if you go to a lower menu say the fourth or fifth, you would still have the third level showing for the title.

What do I add to this or I'm I going to need two different modules for items in the third or greater level menu items?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code should get you close to what you want. It is untested so supplied as is.

It gets the page title from the current/active menu and if it is deeper than level 3 it will step up through the menu items to retrieve the menu title at level 3 and assign it to the page title property.

```
<?php
$menuItems      = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$currentMenu    = $menuItems->getActive();
$menuLevel      = $currentMenu->level;
$pageTitle      = $currentMenu->title;
$parentMenu     = $currentMenu;

//Step up the menu tree until you get to level 3 menu item values.
while ($menuLevel > 3)
{
    $menuId     = $parentMenu->parent;
    $parentMenu = $menuItems->$menuId;
    $pageTitle  = $parentMenu->title;
    $menuLevel  = $parentMenu->level;
}

echo $pageTitle;
```